# Can't set textarea value with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to start saying that I'm not that experienced with the technologies that I'm using, I'm doing this project to practice using them.

I just downloaded `JetBrains Webstorm` and created a `Foundation Project`.

I created a `<textarea>` and I want to bind it to a value I defined in my AngularJS controller. The controller code is very simple (it's in my `main.js` file):

```
var readerApp = angular.module("readerApp", []);

function ReaderCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.data = {
        text = "Default text"
    }
}
```

So I only have a simple text that I want to bind like this: `ng-model="{{data.text}}"`

Although when I do that, the `<textarea>` still doesn't show anything. I'll post the entire HTML page, maybe there's a small detail I'm missing, but it seems right to me

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="readerApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Speed Reader | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns large-text-center">
        <h1>Welcome to Speed Reader!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="panel" ng-controller="ReaderCtrl">
            <h3>Insert your text here! </h3>

            <textarea id="textarea" rows="25" ng-model="{{data.text}}"></textarea>

            <a href="#" class="medium success button right">Start reading</a>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).foundation();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `=` in the object is wrong, do: `$scope.data = { text: "Default text" };`. Also use `ng-model` without the `{{...}}`, i.e. `ng-model="data.text"`.

Comment: Such simple details, I can't believe I missed those. Sorry for the rookie mistakes, thank you very much for your assitance @NikosParaskevopoulos